# Set the event to drop the table if no records exist

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table `bus` with 2 events. One `AutoDelete` to maintain the data in the bus table (This one works) and the other one to delete the table if no records exist in the table. `AutoDelete` I dont know how can I set the condition as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bus` in the event `DropBusTable` to get it to work since I dont have time as the other one I have condition.

I appreciate any help.

```
   stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus"
            + "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
            + "route int(11) NOT NULL,"
            + "latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
            + "longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
            + "created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

    stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete "
            + "ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE "
            + "DO "
            + "DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)");

    // I tried this statement here but it does not work.
    stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  DropBusTable "
            + "Do "
            + "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  bus");
```

Comment: Why would you like to delete an empty table? As fare as security is concerned this is a bad design to allow application to delete DB tables.

Comment: @Max I would like to reset the counter `id` to 1 if the table is empty how can I do that with the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the counter with:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

by adding it to your existing task:

```
  stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete "
            + "ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE "
            + "DO BEGIN"
            + "DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3  MINUTE);"
            + "ALTER TABLE bus AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;"
            + "END;");
```

See this **[article](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/)** for more info.

Comment: I know what the statement is but I do not know how can I set it with the condition in the event.